# Darknet: Loss decreases but iou stay very low when training 1 class

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, object-detection-api, darknet

I'm training Darknet Yolo with 1 class (Have 9000 training examples!), but I have this sample of the output:

```sh
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 150 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.003734, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.003734
```

The iou remains **constant** at 0.07 and a very low class loss.

```sh
 (next mAP calculation at 1000 iterations) 
 250: 0.004589, 0.011130 avg loss, 0.000004 rate, 7.071465 seconds, 16000 images, 2.931760 hours left
```

What is the problem that causes this **constant** small iou?

**Details**

The most relevant parts of the *yolov4-custom.cfg* file:

```sh
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=512
height=512
channels=1
momentum=0.949
decay=0.0005

max_batches = 2000
steps=1600,1800

...

filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401
classes=1
```

The *obj.data* file:

```sh
classes = 1
train  = /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/train.txt
names = /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/data/obj.names
backup = /content/darknet/build/darknet/x64/backup/
```

The *obj.name* file:

```sh
Object
```

Comment: Please write you IOU function. Are you training on IOU loss function or any other? Which library are you using (tensorflow / pytorch etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change cfg file. If you have <= 3 classes, you need to set max_batches = 6000, steps: 4800, 5400. Then you need to set all of 3 yolo layers and prev. layers' filters. And loss should become low, that is training and your model as it was shown trained very well.